# How to compile graph-tool in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, boost-python, graph-tool

I am trying to compile and install graph-tool version 2.26 in ubuntu using 
./configure but I am getting following error

checking for boostlib >= 1.55.0 (105500)... yes
checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... yes
checking whether boost_python is the correct library... no
checking whether boost_python-py27 is the correct library... no
checking whether boost_python-py27 is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python-py27 is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python-py35 is the correct library... no
checking whether boost_python-py35 is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python-py35 is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python is the correct library... (cached) no
checking whether boost_python3 is the correct library... no
configure: error: No usable boost::python found

I have tried ./configure --with-python-boost=no  but have obtained the same error ...

Can anyone please help